# Get first element with condition in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following Angular 1.0 code:

```
  <div ng-repeat="ebook in vml.ebooks">
    <img data-ng-src="{{ ebook.files.filter(function (v) { return v.type === 'ebook.cover'; })[0].url }}" />
  </div>
```

But I get the error:

```
"Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'ebook' is an unexpected token at column 55 of the expression ['ebook.files.filter(function (v) { return v.type === 'ebook.cover'; })[0].url'] starting at [ebook.cover'; })[0].url'].
```

How can I solve this?

Would it be possible to convert this into a filter?

On a list of objects (files) I need to get the first one with a given type.

Comment: this sort of logic should be in controller or custom filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `Array.prototype.filter` method in Angular expression. However, you should be able to do it with Angular filter. Corresponding expression will look like this:

```
data-ng-src="{{ (ebook.files | filter:{type:'ebook.cover'})[0].url }}"
```

Comment: This is not working. Always returns the first one in the list not the one with type equal to ebook.cover. Any idea why?

Comment: I think you meant "{{ (ebook.files | filter: { type : 'ebook.cover' })[0].url }}" ... In this case it works.

Comment: You are right, I meant `{ type : 'ebook.cover' }` of course.

Answer (score 2):

Sure... create your own filter and then pass it in the data-ng-src:

```
data-ng-src="{{ ebook.files | myFilter:'ebook.cover' }}
```

Comment: I think this is not quite what OP wants. First of all, it needs custom filter `myFilter`, then it would also return filtered array, while `ngSrc` would expect `url`.

Comment: It depends on how you implement the filter. Mathew did not write the code for the filter but he just gave enough info for Miguel to solve his issue

Comment: Yes, I would like to filter by Type but get an array or the first item in the list. I would like to indicate to the filter if I would like all matches or the first match. But always get the file. Then ouside it specify which property to use. But I am open to suggestions